# Handle tap event in parent widget

Tags: flutter

In my app tree I have two widgets:

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () => print('Outer'),
   child: IconButton(
     icon: Icon(Icons.add),
     onPressed: () => print('Inner')),
   ),
)
```

Both of them are trying to react to touch event but only child's callback is invoked (which is default behaviour). Is it possible to define widgets in a way that will prevent ancestor from propagating touch event to its children? Or maybe the only way is to implement such behaviour on your own, e.g. by making use of `GestureArena`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [AbsorbPointer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) widget:

> A widget that absorbs pointers during hit testing.
>
> When absorbing is true, this widget prevents its subtree from
>   receiving pointer events by terminating hit testing at itself. It
>   still consumes space during layout and paints its child as usual. It
>   just prevents its children from being the target of located events,
>   because it returns true from RenderBox.hitTest.

You can use it like this:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => print('Outer'),
  child: AbsorbPointer(
    child: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => print('Inner'),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Works as intended, thank you. Likewise, can you think of a solution where both parent and child are notified about tap event?